# Logout issue after redirect to cancel/success URL when make a payment with Perfect Money in Laravel

Tags: laravel, payment

I have a payment gateway with Perfect Money in my Laravel project.

I generated a form according to the this doc: https://perfectmoney.com/sci_generator.html

The problem is that the redirected page when payment succeeds or fails does not work as expected.
The URL is set exactly in the browser, but it's actually displayed "419 | PAGE EXPIRED" on the page.

It seemed like a CSRF Token problem, so I added the redirect URLs to the *`VerifyCsrfToken.php`* file.
Then page 419 does not appear, but it seems like the session is lost.
It is redirect to the login page after I click cancel button from the form supported PerfectMoney System: https://perfectmoney.com/api/step1.asp

I don't understand how the redirection URL called by Perfect Money System can clear the session on my system.

I did some research on this issue and found that there were several developers who had experienced the same issue as me.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/perfect-money-integration-some-problems

But I couldn't find an exact solution.

Am I using something wrong?

---

Updated:

I discovered something.
If I press the payment button in my app to access the payment form provided by perfect money, I can see this page in action with the data I submitted.
https://perfectmoney.com/api/step1.asp
[image]

However, when this URL is accessed in the in-cognitor method, the form page is not displayed, but the welcome page is displayed (of course).
https://perfectmoney.com/?welcome=1

What's interesting here is that once I press the submit payment button on my app and access the form displayed at the above, even if I copy the above URL and paste it into the browser **without pressing the payment submission button**, the data I submitted is displayed as is.
ex: Payment To, Amount

As you can see in the URL, there is no data I submitted in the URL above, but we can see the data I submitted in the form using only that URL.

I think this may have been done by saving the data I submitted as the session on their server and then deleting it after the payment was cancelled.
Even if that's the case, I don't understand why my server's session is deleted when canceled.

Any idea?

** If someone can solve this problem, I won't hesitate to pay))
Thanks for the advice

Comment: Are you using cookie session in your app ? If so what are the attributes of the cookie ? Is it a lax one ?

Comment: I'm using Auth provided by the Laravel framework. exactly: ``Auth::attempt($credentials)``

Comment: I mean in your webbrowser, in your main app, do you have a session cookie ?

Comment: No. I don't have set any cookie.

Comment: You said that "it seems like the session is lost". I had same problem too and the problem was I was going from website A to website B (payment) and back to A after some times. But the session cookie on website A was `SameSite: Lax` and not sent back when going from B to A website. I solved it by setting the cookie to be `SameSite: None` with `secure`attribute.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your solution. By setting it that way, the problem of session loss and logout when redirected was resolved. However, when the redirection URL is a protected route and the PM is redirected to the URL, Auth is not recognized and a page expire error is displayed on the page. In short, my goal is to ensure that the URL redirected after payment processing in PM is protected, that is, to a URL where logged in user information can be read. Any idea?

Comment: Please write as an answer for developers facing the same problem as me. I'll approve it to the right answer.

Comment: I'll do for sure. Glad it helps you concerning the session lost problem

Comment: If the session is expired in your website, it should go back to same behaviour as session cookie not being sent problem. You can try it by keeping a webpage open on your website and delete the session cookie when another tab in browser is in payment page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem too and the problem was :

I was going from website A (with session cookie) to website B (payment) and back to A after some times and session was lost.
The problem was that the session cookie on website A was `SameSite: Lax` (in fact `SameSite` attribute was not set and changed defaulting from `None` to `Lax`).

By being `Lax` the cookie was not sent back when going from B to A website.

I solved it by setting the cookie to be `SameSite: None` with `secure` attributes.

References :

- https://chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592
- https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/